# Google Maps API setting Button Click Listeners wrong

Tags: android, google-maps, button, listener, onclicklistener

I am trying to setup a Google Map in a fragment and am running into some issues trying to get the buttons to listen properly. I have the following code:

```
public DefaultMap extends android,.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
                if (mMap != null) {

                }
            }
        };

        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
//        mAutocompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.TFSearch);
//        mAutocompleteView.setAdapter(new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line));
        searchSetup(v);
        zoomSetup(v);
        setupMapType(v);
        return v;
    }
    //an example of one of the setup functions
    public void setupMapType(View view) {
        typeMapButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.TFtype);
        typeMapButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL) {
                    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                } else {
                    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

relevant pieces of map_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/mapScreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:context=".DefaultMap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/map_type"
                android:id="@+id/TFtype"
                android:onClick="onTypeMap"
                tools:context=".DefaultMap"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And I am receiving the following error when clicking the buttons (same for all 4 buttons):

```
 11-15 22:57:22.481 32523-32523/oose2017.place2b E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getMapType()' on a null object reference
 11-15 22:57:22.481 32523-32523/myproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at myproject.interfaces.map.DefaultMap$5.onClick(DefaultMap.java:153)
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can fix these issues?

Comment: Show `map_fragment.xml` file also

Comment: updated to show map_fragment.xml snippet

Comment: See following example http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-supportmapfragment-example/

Comment: Currently you are doing it both way using xml and code. use one approach to add SupportMapFragment Fragment either using code or using xml

Comment: is there no way to use the map in a fragment and not a fragment activity? I am using this map fragment within another activity and my goal is to not need to have an activity defining the entire thing

Comment: i originally had it in a FragmentActivity but as I need to be able to use it from within a drawer I changed it to a fragment, which works perfectly as far as displaying the map goes but the functions are all broken

Comment: Please see following post for adding Map in Fragment http://droidarc.blogspot.in/2014/03/supportmapfragment-problem-when-loding.html change DefaultMap as MyFragment

Comment: Thanks a bunch dude! Worked perfectly. Should update to an answer instead of a comment so I can select yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SupportMapFragment.newInstance()` for getting new instance of `SupportMapFragment` for adding it from Fragment and also remove `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` from xml of `DefaultMap` Fragment.

See following tutorial for more information :

[SupportMapFragment problem when loding in Fragment class](http://droidarc.blogspot.in/2014/03/supportmapfragment-problem-when-loding.html)